# Upload Bulk Images in Box

Tags: box-api

We are uploading thousands of file to a Box location thorough Java API. It is taking more than a day to upload these many files to Box. Is there a way to upload files in Bulk in Box using Java API? Would that help in improving performance?

Here is the reference code that we are using: https://github.com/kendomen/BoxJavaJWTExamples/blob/master/src/com/nike/box/UploadFileAsAppUser.java

Comment: You should make some calculations to determine if you're saturating your network bandwidth, and if not, where the slowdowns are (opening files, rate limiting, etc.)  If you're already saturating your bandwidth, bulk uploading isn't going to make any difference.

Comment: A few days ago I tried it without Box upload (Simply pacing it to the same server) and it took about 3 hours.